# UITableview HeaderView reloading

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have created Dropdown Tableview with multi sections & each section as one header view. Tapping a button in header view, I am inserting one row to that section & tapping on same button in removing row from that section.

On removing the row from that section. The dequeued Headerview is getting changes from custom view to native view.

Code :

```
[self.rTable registerClass:[headerCell class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"cellHeader"];


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


headerCell *detailView = nil;

       detailView = (headerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"cellHeader"];

 return detailView;

}
```

Button Action Function :

```
-(void)detailViewButtonSelectedAtIndex:(int)index;
{
    if(selectedSection != -1){

        previousSelected = selectedSection;

        [self.rTable beginUpdates];

        [self.rTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:previousSelected]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.rTable endUpdates];


        selectedSection = -1;

        headerCell *view = (headerCell *)[self.routeTable headerViewForSection:previousSelected];

        [view.routeCell.detailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    if(previousSelected != index){

        selectedSection = index;

        [self.rTable beginUpdates];

        [self.rTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:selectedSection]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];

        [self.rTable endUpdates];

        previousSelected = -1;



    }else{
        previousSelected = -1;
    }


}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear what you want to achieve? can you explain little

Comment: Why custom header view is turning into normal header view (i.e with label & Image) was question?

Comment: its because your are doing dequeue your cell based on indexpath, do not use UItableViewCell for header view, just create a separate view in storybord for that!